# Mean value theorem of a function in [a,b]

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Is Mean Value Theorem (Rolle's Theorem) applicable for the following function:

$$\log \frac{x^2 + ab}{(a+b)x}$$

in the interval $(a,b)$

My text says that it's applicable. But isn't the function discontinuous when $a<0$ and $b>0$? As this interval include $0$ at which the function is not defined and hence is not continuous.

Comment: Yes, there should be a condition a,b>0.

Comment: Ofcourse you are right.

Answer (score -1):

yes this function fulfills the conditions of Rolle's theorem.
$f(x)$ is continous at the interval $[a,b]$ as a composition of continously functions and is differentiable. Also we can prove that $f(a)=f(b)=0$.
Sonnhard.

Comment: But if we plot a graph with a<0 and b>0 we will have a discontinuous graph, which obviously violates the laws of Rolle's Theorem and hence does not hold it. (I presume my text has made a mistake).